# Unable to view files (copied from computer)

Tags: file-transfer

I've been trying to transfer some apk files from my computer to my Galaxy Nexus.  From the information I read, transferring files from PC to android smartphone is supposed to be as easy as drag and drop. I connected my phone to the computer via usb cable, chose MTP option, allow unknown sources installation, and I can access the internal storage of my phone (DCIM, Download folders, etc) just fine.
Then I copied the apk files to a folder (say, Download), disconnect the phone from the computer. On the phone, go into downloads folder and I cannot see the apk files at all !

I dont have any file manager installed, could that be the problem ? How can I install my first file manager through pc ?

Comment: I believe you will not see apk files unless you have the proper security setting 'Unknown sources' checked to allow non-Google Play apks to install. See Settings>Security>Unknown Sources, then try to find and install it again.

Comment: @wbogacz quoting the question: "allow unknown sources installation" – so that was already done. Though it shouldn't be required to *see* the files, just to *install* them ;) // Lorenz: what did you use to browse your downloads? I'm not sure, but it could be the "shipped viewer" uses some database to record downloads, instead of simply "listing the folder". Using a [file manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman)/file explorer should reveal the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Enable USB debugging mode (Go to About Phone, tap the Build number field 7 times to enable Developer Options, then go there)
2.Open the internet browser
3.In the address bar, write the path of .apk file e.g. "file:///sdcard/example.apk".

Answer (score 1):

> I dont have any file manager installed, could that be the problem ? How can I install my first file manager through pc ?

- Go to the [play store](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en) and look
  for a file browser of your liking. Install it on your phone.
- Connect your phone to your computer. Go to command line/terminal. Make sure you have adb installed, if not install it now. 
  Use the [adb command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary) `install <path-to-apk>`.